# Navsat_transform_node does not subscribe to IMU topic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently trying to use the navsat_transform_node from the robot_localization package in a ROS-Gazebo simulation. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with ROS kinetic and Gazebo 7.

In order to work, this node needs to subscribe to 3 differents topics : an odometry topic with nav_msgs/Odometry message, an IMU topic with sensor_msgs/Imu and a GPS topic with sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.

My problem is that, when launching the navsat_transform_node does not subscribe to my IMU topic, even if the message type of the IMU topic published by gazebo is sensor_msgs/Imu. However, the node does subscribe to the odom and gps topics.

Here is my launch file (taken from [the robot localization wiki](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html)) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true">
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu_data" />
    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/gps/fix" />
    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odom" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Here is the IMU code from the URDF file of my robot model :

```
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/> <!-- 0 1 0 -->
    <origin xyz="${length_chassis*(5/16)} 0 ${height_chassis-(wheel_radius/2)}"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu_link"/>
  </joint>

<link name="imu_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.001"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size=" ${IMU_size} ${IMU_size} ${IMU_size}"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="green"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="${IMU_size} ${IMU_size} ${IMU_size}"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
```

And here is the IMU plugin :

```
<gazebo >
    <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <frameId>imu_link</frameId>
      <topicName>/imu_data</topicName>
      <serviceName>imu_service</serviceName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
      <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
      <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
      <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
    </plugin>    
</gazebo>
```

When echo-ing the topic /imu_data, I get :

```
---
header: 
  seq: 327
  stamp: 
    secs: 16
    nsecs: 400000000
  frame_id: "imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: 4.69962116857e-06
  y: -4.8838604247e-08
  z: 7.97720664175e-05
  w: 0.999999996807
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -4.49165569326e-13
  y: 6.43295283435e-15
  z: 2.52244385042e-12
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 3.40118210419e-07
  y: 9.18946096526e-05
  z: 9.79999999084
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

Also, @Tom Moore told me to post a sample message for every sensor input, so here is the sample from the topic /odom :

```
---
header: 
  seq: 165673
  stamp: 
    secs: 1661
    nsecs: 260000000
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.267229286097
      y: 0.00580914153162
      z: 0.299999489939
    orientation: 
      x: 1.20893461539e-05
      y: -8.60155713043e-08
      z: 0.0124744407312
      w: 0.999922191064
  covariance: [1e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.000281084109386
      y: -4.7415432993e-06
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 1.31254728036e-05
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

And here, the sample from the /gps/fix topic :

```
---
header: 
  seq: 7159
  stamp: 
    secs: 1794
    nsecs: 500000000
  frame_id: "GPS_link"
status: 
  status: 0
  service: 0
latitude: -30.0602189385
longitude: -51.1739172289
altitude: 9.7517203133
position_covariance: [0.0025010000000000006, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0025010000000000006, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0025010000000000006]
position_covariance_type: 2
---
```

If you have any ideas on how to fix this issue, I will be pleased ! Thank you

EDIT after @cagatayyuruk answer :

- changed the plugin of my IMU from libgazebo_ros_imu.so to libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so because the old one was not able to get imu_link as frame id. (code of the IMU and sample of the IMU's message are updated in the text above)
- after a few test, it seems that the navsat node can only subscribe to the IMU topic when the TF_static between IMU_link and base_link is not set. So when all the tf static of the robot are launched, the navsat node does not work. Maybe I got something wrong in my TF that stop the subscribe of the navsat node to the IMU topic ?

EDIT for the TF Tree on Imgur : https://imgur.com/mVl7iCG

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287090/navsat_transform_node-does-not-subscribe-to-imu-topic/) by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-04-03**:
I'm a little suspicious that it has something to do with your TFs. If you could post your TF tree (without trying to run navsat transform) that would be useful.

**Comment by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) on 2018-04-04**:
I can not post image since I do not have enough karma point to upload a file

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-04-04**:
Upload it somewhere else and post the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple things:

1. Your IMU data has a `frame_id` of *imu_link*, and your GPS has a `frame_id` of *GPS_link*. You need to define static transforms from *imu_link* -> *base_link* and from *gps_link* to *base_link*.
2. Keep in mind that, once `navsat_transform_node` gets a single usable IMU message, it [unsubscribes](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/f25a0753f6847c6e61ce54a82c878805380b21ae/src/navsat_transform.cpp#L196) from the IMU data. It only needs a single earth-referenced heading measurement.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) on 2018-04-13**:
Thank you for your answer. It seems that with the correct static transforms, the node is working fine !

**Comment by [Jimeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/36678/jimeat/) on 2018-07-26**:
What is the best way to get earth referenced heading measurement from IMU?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-08-03**:
Please ask a separate question.

**Comment by [A.Mahrous](https://answers.ros.org/users/44775/a.mahrous/) on 2019-09-30**:
could you please tell me how you solved this in details?, thanks in advance.

**Comment by [atwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/51499/atwin/) on 2020-06-10**:
can you please show the launch file with the correct static transforms. I seem to have this exact same issue and have tried to write static transforms for both base_link -> imu_link and base_link -> gps (my GPS frame_id--from bag1) only to gain no result.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-03-22**:
@Tom Moore
hi,
regardin the first point which you mentioned, in the tf tree i can see that gps and imu link through a number of other links are connected to the base_link. i have also checked the tf between gps_link to base_link AND  imu_link -> base_link. it starts publishing. so in this case d i need to define the static transforms again??

thanks

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-04-08**:
Please ask a new question.